# capture and retrieve image in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am new to iOS 5.0,

I want to know that,

Is there any method to capture the image from camera and retrieve it in application in iOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Camera Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html).